# How to reverse generate a URL from a route on Play 2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Under Play 1.4.x if I wanted to reverse generate a URL I might use something like:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap();
map.put("myParam", myParam);
ActionDefinition ad = Router.reverse("MyAction.query", map);
String url = ad.url;
```

According to the unfailingly terse Play 2.x [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaRouting), under Play 2 with Scala I'm supposed to use a Redirect:

```
val action = Action {Redirect(routes.MyAction.query(myParam))}
```

but what do I do with the action to acquire the actual URL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
val relative = routes.MyAction.query(myParam).url
```

or absolute

```
val url = routes.MyAction.query(myParam).absoluteURL()
```

or absolute https

```
val securedUrl = routes.MyAction.query(myParam).absoluteURL(true)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with an implicit request: `def blah = Action { implicit request => val url = routes.MyAction.query(myParam).absoluteURL() ...`

Comment: Does not work in play 2.1.x, "value query is not a member of play.api.mvc.Call"