# How to reverse generate an absolute URL from a route on Play 2 Java?

Tags: java, url, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'd like to get the absolute URL from a controller in Play 2 Java. I found the [exact same question for Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591396/how-to-reverse-generate-a-url-from-a-route-on-play-2), but I can't make it work in Java.

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    public static Result myMethod() {
        return ok();
    }

    public static Result test() {
        Logger.info(routes.MyController.myMethod().url); // Doesn't work !
        Logger.info(routes.MyController.myMethod().absoluteURL()); // Doesn't work !
        Logger.info(routes.MyController.myMethod().absoluteURL(true)); // Doesn't work !
        return ok();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add request to `absoluteURL()`

```
routes.MyController.myMethod().absoluteURL(request());
```

Comment: Just a note: this works because absoluteURL uses Request object to find the domain.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how it knows whether to use http url or https? Issue is my app is behind proxy which supports both http and https. When i call this function via https, it returns me the url prefixed with http and my browser blocks the content because of mixed content policy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this works in 2.0, but since you're using Java it might do the trick. I use it in 1.2.4.

```
Router.getFullUrl("Controller.action")
```

Good luck !

Edit : I import play.mvc.Router so if this doesn't exist in 2.0 you might find something similar.

Also, this is play's 2.0 documentation on routing, check Reverse routing, maybe it will help.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaRouting

Comment: Too bad, that was pretty useful. From what I read from the documentation, each time a controller is used in the routes conf, it generates a reverse controller. It looks like this `controllers.routes.Controller.action(args)`. I edited my answer with the link to the documentation.