# Get URL of deployed playframework application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

How to get URL where is current play application deployed? In servlet environment you can query container, but play framework app is running in its own Netty container.

I need to know where is application deployed because i am displaying full URL links to user.

Comment: request.uri contains only relative part "/" no hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your intention correctly you want just to use an `absolute` url, so similar question (and answer) should be your solution: [How to reverse generate an absolute URL from a route on Play 2 Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11158750/1066240)

(just note, that you can also use absolute routes in the views).