# Get the base url of a Play application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I want to obtain the current base url of an application which usually `http://localhost:9000/` at localhost and `http://mydomain.com` at a server. If the future I might start using https.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you read [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158750/how-to-reverse-generate-an-absolute-url-from-a-route-on-play-2-java)
answer?

Comment: @Artsiom, as expected, `Router.getFullUrl("Controller.action")` - no such a method, `routes.MyController.myMethod().absoluteURL(request());` - the same.

Comment: @Artsiom, but I don't want to refer to a controller and action to get the base Url because they are subject to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Play Framework are you using ?

If you are using Play 1.x, you should manually specify the base url of your application using an application.conf variable. This is the way I do in order to retrieve base url for my applications. For example :

```
application.baseUrl=http://localhost:9000
%devcloud.application.baseUrl=http://dev-url.com
%prod.application.baseUrl=http://prod-url.com
```

With Play Framework 2.x, you could use additional configuration file (thus variables values depending on the environment - prod, dev, test ...), as explained here : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration

These solutions work especially if you do not want to depend on an Action or a Controller. Else, you can retrieve the absolute URL using the Request within the Action.

Comment: but I don't want to depend on a port it happens to work either.

Comment: Then you must also add a configuration variable for the port. Changing the running port of your application (even if in dev mode it isn't so important), or the protocol (http or https), is not a minor decision, and thus it is not so bad to handle one or two variables ;)

Comment: Then I'll have to change it all the time when the app is running on the port which is different than 9000.

Answer (score 2):

And then try to obtain baseUrl:
`play.Play.application().configuration().getString("application.baseUrl")`

Comment: I don't want to depend on a port it happens to run. I want it to be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `play.Play.application().configuration().getString("application.baseUrl");` is depricated in play latest version. so here is the latest solution to the problem :

First Inject the configuration into the class :

```
   @Inject
    Configuration configuration;
```

Then use it like :

```
String baseUrl = configuration.getString("application.baseUrl");
```